# How to pass an array to the main view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

It seems that I just can't pass an array in another function into main view.

My index() function is =>

```
public function index()
    {


    $this->load->view('anasayfa');  


    }
```

My aforementioned function is =>

```
public function pozisyon_tutma()
    {...

    ....
print_r(array_values($pozisyon));
$GLOBALS['pozisyong'] = $pozisyon;
}
```

which works...

I am seeking something like =>

```
public function index()
    {

    $this->pozisyon_tutma();
    $data['hoppa']=$GLOBALS['pozisyong'];

    $this->load->view('anasayfa', $data);   


    }
```

and I am seeking in view 'anasayfa' (which is the main view) something like this code to work=>

```
<?php  

print_r(array_values($hoppa));

 ?>
```

However this code gives the following error=>

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: hoppa

Filename: views/anasayfa.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\views\anasayfa.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 24
Function: view

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Filename: views/anasayfa.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\views\anasayfa.php
Line: 19
Function: array_values

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 24
Function: view

File: D:\wamp\www\proje\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

All help will be much appreciated. I checked all other threads in stackoverflaw and could not make any of them work in my case... Thank you all

Comment: `$GLOBALS` don't use these! `pozisyon_tutma()` should return the value do NOT assign it to a `$GLOBALS`. Then `$data['hoppa'] = $this->pozisyon_tutma();` would write the value straight into the array.

Comment: Thank you @mic... pozisyon_tutma() function is in another page. What do we do then. Awaiting your response. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You should use in your controller:

```
$data = array('key1'=>$value1, 'key2'=>$value2, 'key3'=>functionX()....);
$this->load->view('yourview.php',$data);
```

And in the view to access to the array of values:

```
echo $key1; // prints $value1.
echo $key2; // prints $value2.
```

Also, you could use $_SESSION to store some variables in CI. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way=>

```
public function index()
    {

        require('Hesaplama.php');
        $Hesaplama = new Hesaplama();
        $data['hoppa']=$Hesaplama->pozisyon_tutma();

    $this->load->view('anasayfa', $data);   


    }
```

It works. I returned $pozisyon which is an array as @mic suggested. I will keep the suggestions of @JP. Aulet in case I need them in the near future. Thank you all...

Comment: Glad I could help :)